# Javascript - Remove array elements if all elements are null

Tags: javascript, node.js

Cosider the following array:

```
let array = [
 {Product Title: "Milk", Product Variant: "2L", Quantity: "3"},
 {Product Title: "Water", Product Variant: "", Quantity: "3"},
 {Product Title: "Pepsi", Product Variant: "", Quantity: ""},
 {Product Title: "", Product Variant: "", Quantity: ""}
 {Product Title: "", Product Variant: "", Quantity: ""}
]
```

How do I remove elements from the array, if all the elements have no value?

What I've tried:

```
let contents = []

for (let i in array) {
  Object.keys(array[i]).forEach((k) => array[i][k] == "" && delete array[i][k])
  contents.push(array[i])
}

console.log(contents)
```

but this returns:

```
0: {Product Title: "Milk", Product Variant: "2L", Quantity: "3"},
1: {Product Title: "Water", Quantity: "3"},
2: {Product Title: "Pepsi"},
3: {}
4: {}
```

While I would want:

```
0: {Product Title: "Milk", Product Variant: "2L", Quantity: "3"},
1: {Product Title: "Water", Product Variant: "", Quantity: "3"},
2: {Product Title: "Pepsi", Product Variant: "", Quantity: ""}
```

Comment: `const filteredArray = array.filter(o => Object.values(o).reduce((f, i) => (f || i.length > 0) , false));`

Comment: Have you considered using Lists ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could join all values and take the string for filtering.

```js
const
    array = [{ ProductTitle: "Milk", ProductVariant: "2L", Quantity: "3" }, { ProductTitle: "Water", ProductVariant: "", Quantity: "3" }, { ProductTitle: "Pepsi", ProductVariant: "", Quantity: "" }, { ProductTitle: "", ProductVariant: "", Quantity: "" }, { ProductTitle: "", ProductVariant: "", Quantity: "" }],
    result = array.filter(o => Object.values(o).join(''));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You beat me to it again ! Always nice to see your answers! 

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. Really like the one line solution

Comment: @CarstenMassmann Agreed. Her answers are amazing! She is a developer from GOD.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```js
const array = [
  {"Product Title": "Milk", "Product Variant": "2L", Quantity: "3"},
  {"Product Title": "Water", "Product Variant": "", Quantity: "3"},
  {"Product Title": "Pepsi", "Product Variant": "", Quantity: ""},
  {"Product Title": "", "Product Variant": "", Quantity: ""},
  {"Product Title": "", "Product Variant": "", Quantity: ""}
 ]
const res=array.filter(e=>Object.values(e).join("")>"")

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let newArray = contents.filter(value => Object.keys(value).length !== 0);
```

Use filter on your array to have a new one without empty objects

Answer (score 0):

Use array.splice(...) to delete or replace at a specific array index or range.

Or array.filter(...) to create a new array with only elements fitting a certain criteria.

UPDATE:
delete(array[index] ) will not reindex the array after deleting the item, nor the change the array length or the indices of adjacent members.

Answer (score 0):

Objective is to filter the array and retain only those objects where at least one value is not-empty (ie, element's length is above 0).

**Sample-code**

```
const getFilteredArray = (arr = array) => (
  arr.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).reduce(
    (f, i) => (f || i.length > 0),
    false
  ))
);
```

**Explanation**

- Use `filter` to keep only specific objects in the array
- Use `.reduce` to iterate over each object's values
- The aggregator `f` is initially assumed to be `false`
- If any one value is non-empty (ie, length > 0), then aggregator is set to `true`

**Code Snippet**

```js
let array = [
 {'Product Title': "Milk", 'Product Variant': "2L", Quantity: "3"},
 {'Product Title': "Water", 'Product Variant': "", Quantity: "3"},
 {'Product Title': "Pepsi", 'Product Variant': "", Quantity: ""},
 {'Product Title': "", 'Product Variant': "", Quantity: ""},
 {'Product Title': "", 'Product Variant': "", Quantity: ""}
];

const getFilteredArray = (arr = array) => (
    arr.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).reduce(
    (f, i) => (f || i.length > 0),
    false
  ))
);

console.log(getFilteredArray());
```

Improvement: Consider using Array `.some` instead of `.reduce`.

This uses `.some` instead of `.reduce`.

```
const getFilteredArray = (arr = array) => (
  arr.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).some(
    v => v.length > 0)
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter`, `Object.values`, and `join`. Here is the example:

```js
let array = [
 {ProductTitle: "Milk", ProductVariant: "2L", Quantity: "3"},
 {ProductTitle: "Water", ProductVariant: "", Quantity: "3"},
 {ProductTitle: "Pepsi", ProductVariant: "", Quantity: ""},
 {ProductTitle: "", ProductVariant: "", Quantity: ""},
 {ProductTitle: "", ProductVariant: "", Quantity: ""}
]

result = array.filter(e => Object.values(e).join(''));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your answer is a duplicate of the accepted answer. Please make sure that any new answers are unique